# Algorithm to efficiently plan a path to build a pixel structure

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path

I have a problem that I have an unsatisfactory answer to and I would be interested in knowing if there is a better solution I am missing.

The problem is as follows:

Compute a series of `build` and `move` actions a player can take that will construct a pixel structure. A player can move to blocks to their left or right that are at the player's level, one higher, or any distance below as long as that block is empty space and is one above a filled block. The player obeys a sort of gravity and cannot climb higher than one block, but can fall from any height. The player can build to the left or right of the pixel that contains the player, but nowhere else.

These restrictive rules do not allow the player to build any general structure but are a subset of more complex rules which makes the problem slightly easier.

For example, this structure

```
*--
**s
```

where `-` are empty space, `*` are solid areas, and `s` is where the movable character starts,
could be built by `move left`, `place left`, `move right`, `place left`, `move up and left`, `place left`.

The iterative process would look like this in which p represents the current position of the player:

```
---  ---  ---  ---  ---  -p-  *p-
--p  -p-  *p-  *-p  **p  **-  **-
```

There are situations where the player boxes in an area and can no longer access it to build. For example, while trying to build the above example with `place left`, `move up and left`, `place_left`, the player ends up with

```
*p-
-*-
```

and no longer has access to the final block they want to place.

I'd been de-stressing with terraria and decided to make it stressful by trying to figure out an algorithm that could match a human in efficiency with number of actions taken to build a structure. I quickly failed to think of anything clever.

Traversing a graph where each node is the full state of the structure at that time does not work since any place or move action could make completing the structure impossible and, in this framework, we cannot look ahead to see if the action is a dependency of building something else. (Although this is what I ended on as the most realistic algorithm if combined with a simple heuristic and a depth-first search)

The next idea was to construct a dependency graph and traverse that instead as the maximum number of nodes would be linear to the build size instead of factorial. Each action depends on previous actions taken so it seemed like a safe bet. However, I found that the two way coupling between dependencies of building and moving caused issues with trying to do a simple path finding between the start and end conditions. For example, to `move up and left` as we did above, it is a requirement that we have already placed the block we will be standing on as well as having moved to the rightmost block. As far as I know, having both of those requirements to have to move to that node means I can't use this method.

I also considered a method where dependencies for subsets of the structure are computed beforehand, but that just puts off the issue where at some point you have to deal with the fact that there are multiple dependencies for the same node.

So at the end, I decided that the best way to solve this would be to compute the postive (I must have done this to complete this action) and negative (I cannot have done this) dependencies for each possible action then do a depth first search through the space of all subsets of the built structure using a heuristic of increase positive dependencies while avoiding negative ones. Then maybe at the end you could iteratively improve the result by employing some markov chain method. This solution just does not give me the catharsis I wanted though.

I am a programmer, not a computer scientist, though. I only know of a very small number of algorithms similar to this one which makes me feel like there must be some more efficient method that I am just not seeing. Maybe something with two dependency graphs coupled together for moving and placing individually to avoid that problem of having two requirements for the same node.

If there are papers on similar topics or classes of algorithms I don't know about that would help, I would really appreciate a pointer in the right direction. I kind of feel like hamiltonian path methods are relevant here, but I just can't quite make the connection since you need one hamiltonian path through the building graph, but not through the moving graph and I don't know how to integrate the concept of path-based dependencies into hamiltonian path solvers.

Comment: Could you specify the build and move operations more clearly?  I don't understand what the effect of a build or move operation is, and I don't understand what arguments they accept or what the allowed values for the arguments are.  I'm also not clear on what counts as adjacent (are diagonals ok?  you talk about going multiple levels below; how is that adjacent?).  Why could an operation make another move or build operation impossible?  Please tell us under what conditions the operations are possible or impossible.

Comment: Yes, sorry. The rules were far too vauge. I tried to clarify.

Comment: If a player can move up in one operation, can they move up two levels in two operations (move up one level, then move up again)?

Comment: What is meant by "move to blocks"?  Is that related to what has been built before?  Or does it just mean a position in the grid?

Comment: The player must always be one above a block unless they are on the bottom level and must never occupy the same space as a block.

Comment: However, I do not like this question anymore. I will formulate its basis as a graph theory question and ask it in the relevant place as I just think my question was too broad to be explained or answered well. Thank you for doing what you could with this question.

Comment: What's a block?  Is it a solid place that has previously been built by a "build" operation?  Or a location on the grid (whether solid or empty)?